# shutdown ubuntu clients from ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-server, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to ubuntu environment. i have set up an ubuntu 16.04 server and there are clients running ubuntu 16.04 in the network. I want to know whether it is possible to

shutdown all the clients at 5.30pm everyday automatically with a messagebox asking whether to shutdown or not from which they will select yes or no?

Comment: It's the "ask for ok" the tricky part. Do you mean with something graphical ?

Comment: yes i mean graphical @FedericoGalli

Comment: all the clients share the same user? or do you have a list of the users? do you have an user with sudo privileges on all clients?

Comment: i am using ldap authentication. i have an user with sudo privileges on all clients.@FedericoGalli

Answer (score 0):

this is not a definite answer but rather a direction, its too long so can't go as a comment

1- as root try to type  `who -a` , you should see which user is connected and what their `pid` is

2- then you can use `wall` to broadcast a message to user

now each client need to take action, therefore, you need a script on client machine that gets triggered with a broadcast (say everyday at 5:30PM), which then this client will send a message to the server to either kill the user/logout with specific `pid` or not.